# iText: Why the last item of an unordered html bullet list is not showing on my PDF?

Tags: java, html, parsing, pdf, itext

I'm following the `itextpdf` example http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/htmlworker/HtmlContentForCell.

I'm facing a problem where, whenever there is a `bulletlist` in the html-content that I'm parsing as Elements and filling the `pdfCell` with, everything else shows fine in it except the LAST item is missing. What could cause that?

I have the following code:

```
// Relevant code from main part of the class:

   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 40, 40);
   PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
   document.open();
   document.add(buildContent());
   document.close();

// method that should provide content to the document.

public PdfPTable buildContent() throws IOException {
    InfoList infoList = infoListInstance.get();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    for (InfoListMessage message
            : infolistList.getMessages()) {
        renderMessageMetadata(message, table);
        renderMessageContent(message, table);
    }
    return table;
}

// method where the problem occurs and exception is thrown in the for-loop line

public void renderMessageContent(
        InfoListMessage message,
        PdfPTable table) throws IOException {

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

for (Element e : XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(message.getContent(), null)) {
    cell.addElement(e);
}  
    table.addCell(cell);
}
```

I'm quite sure that it is related to html tags, but I'm usually lost when it comes to the intricacies of html tags. Here's an example HTML with my code. This is what I'm feeding to the XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList as HTML:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <span>Lisätty liitteet</span> 
  <ul> 
   <li>document2.txt.txt (23 B)</li> 
   <li>document1.txt.txt (12 B)</li> 
   <li>document3.txt.txt (27 B)</li> 
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

And here's a screenshot of a cell from the pdf that the application creates:
[image]

Comment: there are many rows? `for-each` loops does not preserve the sort... did you made a count to check if element is missing or misplaced???

Comment: @JordiCastilla Yes, the order doesn't even matter here. The element is not showing in the pdf. Even though it is in that list in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at [HtmlContentForCell2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/HtmlContentForCell2). It's almost similar to the example you refer to, but instead of paragraphs, the HTML consists of an unordered list:

```
public static final String HTML = "<ul><li>Overview&#160;line1</li>"
        + "<li>Overview&#160;line2</li><li>Overview&#160;line3</li>"
        + "<li>Overview&#160;line4</li><li>Overview&#160;line5</li></ul>";
```

There are 5 list items in that list, and when we look at the resulting PDF, we see all 5 of them:

[image]

Of course, this is very simple HTML, used as a proof of concept that the last item of a list does not disappear.

These are some possible reasons why not all items appear:

- Maybe you are nesting lists. Deep nesting of lists isn't supported in the context of tables.
- Maybe there's a small error in the tags. For instance: maybe your list item is missing the `<li>` tag.
- Maybe there's content in the list item that is special and that isn't picked up by XML Worker

For a definitive answer, we'd need to see the HTML. Could you prepare a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) based on [HtmlContentForCell2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/HtmlContentForCell2)?

**Update:**

The HTML you provided is simple and valid. I was able to reproduce your problem, hence we are faced with a bug. I'll file a bug report for this issue.

Note that I was able to work around the problem by adding some extra content after the final `</ul>`: See [HtmlContentForCell3](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/HtmlContentForCell3) and the resulting PDF [html_in_cell3.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/html_in_cell3.pdf). However, that's just a quick fix that works around the bug rather than fixing it. The bug should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for that elaborate answer! Just to possibly save everyone's time, first I just added the html to the question and a screenshot. If that would already be enough for pointing out the problem. I'm horrible with html really, so it's quite possible...

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem. I'll file it as a bug. Note: if I add extra content after the final `</ul>`, even if it's just `&nbsp;`, the problem disappears. See http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/HtmlContentForCell3 That's not a good solution, though. The bug needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you once again. You're the best. Instant reply, help, bug filing, workaround. Wow.

Answer (score 0):

If you get all elements from request, but you cannot see the last one inserted in the table is because last row of `table(2)` has not all elements needed (in your case table needs 2 elements per row), use [complete](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#complete) to mark last row as finished **before returning it**...

In `public void renderMessageContent` method if `XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(` has an odd number of elements, you won't see last one:

```
for (Element e : XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(message.getContent(), null))
    cell.addElement(e);

table.addCell(cell);   // here you only add one cell to a 2 column table!!!!
```

Comment: I would assume that the cell in the first column is added in the `renderMessageMetadata()` method.

Comment: Yes, that's true. The first column is added in the renderMessageMetadata(). Maybe I should've shown that in the bit of code in the question.